# Error installing a simple haskell program

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal

I'm trying to install a simple haskell program:

https://github.com/manugunther/hal-gui

The installation instructions are:

```
$> sudo apt-get install ghc 
$> sudo apt-get install cabal-install 
$> sudo apt-get install git

$> git clone https://github.com/manugunther/hal-gui
$> git submodule update --init --recursive

$> cd hal-gui
$> cabal install Cabal 
$> cabal install fun/equ/equ.cabal
$> sudo apt-get install --force-yes -y alex happy
$> cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
$> sudo apt-get install --force-yes -y libgtksourceview2.0-dev ;
$> cabal install fun/fun.cabal
$> cabal install hal/hal.cabal
$> cabal install --only-dependencies

$> ghci
Prelude> :l HGUI/Main.hs
Prelude> main
```

But i get an error in this step:

```
$> cabal install fun/equ/equ.cabal

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
equ-0.2.1 depends on lens-4.13 which failed to install.
lens-4.13 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Version information:

```
$ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1

$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library 

$ ghc-pkg list
    /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.14.0
   GLUT-2.1.2.2
   HTTP-4000.2.3
   HUnit-1.2.4.2
   MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.4
   OpenGL-2.2.3.1
   QuickCheck-2.4.2
   array-0.4.0.0
   base-4.5.0.0
   bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
   binary-0.5.1.0
   bytestring-0.9.2.1
   cgi-3001.1.8.2
   containers-0.4.2.1
   deepseq-1.3.0.0
   directory-1.1.0.2
   extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
   fgl-5.4.2.4
   filepath-1.3.0.0
   ghc-7.4.1
   ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
   haskell-src-1.0.1.5
   haskell2010-1.1.0.1
   haskell98-2.0.0.1
   hoopl-3.8.7.3
   hpc-0.5.1.1
   html-1.0.1.2
   integer-gmp-0.4.0.0
   mtl-2.1.1
   network-2.3.0.13
   old-locale-1.0.0.4
   old-time-1.1.0.0
   parallel-3.2.0.2
   parsec-3.1.2
   pretty-1.1.1.0
   process-1.1.0.1
   random-1.0.1.1
   regex-base-0.93.2
   regex-compat-0.95.1
   regex-posix-0.95.1
   rts-1.0
   stm-2.3
   syb-0.3.6.1
   template-haskell-2.7.0.0
   text-0.11.2.0
   time-1.4
   transformers-0.3.0.0
   unix-2.5.1.0
   xhtml-3000.2.1
   zlib-0.5.3.3
/home/gonzalo/.ghc/i386-linux-7.4.1/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.22.4.0
   MissingH-1.3.0.1
   MonadRandom-0.4
   StateVar-1.1.0.1
   adjunctions-4.2.1
   base-orphans-0.4.2
   bifunctors-5
   binary-0.7.6.1
   cereal-0.4.1.1
   comonad-4.2.7.2
   contravariant-1.3.2
   distributive-0.4.4
   either-4.4.1
   equ-0.2.1
   exceptions-0.8.0.2
   fgl-5.5.2.1
   free-4.12.1
   fun-0.2
   hal-0.0.1
   hashable-1.2.3.3
   hslogger-1.2.9
   kan-extensions-4.2.2
   lens-4.12.3
   lens-4.13
   mmorph-1.0.4
   monad-control-1.0.0.4
   mtl-2.2.1
   nats-1
   network-2.6.2.1
   parsec-3.1.9
   prelude-extras-0.4
   primitive-0.6
   profunctors-5.1.1
   reference-0.1
   reflection-2
   reflection-2.1
   regex-base-0.93.2
   regex-compat-0.95.1
   regex-posix-0.95.2
   semigroupoids-5.0.0.2
   semigroups-0.16.2.2
   strict-0.3.2
   tagged-0.8.1
   transformers-0.4.3.0
   transformers-base-0.4.4
   transformers-compat-0.4.0.4
   unordered-containers-0.2.5.1
   utf8-string-0.3.8
   vector-0.11.0.0
   void-0.7
```

error information:

I get no error when I execute "$> cabal install lens"

But i get this when i execute "$> cabal install fun/equ/equ.cabal"

```
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/lens-4.13-14792/lens-4.13/Setup.lhs, /tmp/lens-4.13-14792/lens-4.13/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/lens-4.13-14792/lens-4.13/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring lens-4.13...
Building lens-4.13...
Preprocessing library lens-4.13...
[ 1 of 81] Compiling Data.Map.Lens    ( src/Data/Map/Lens.hs, dist/build/Data/Map/Lens.o )
[ 2 of 81] Compiling Paths_lens       ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_lens.hs, dist/build/Paths_lens.o )
[ 3 of 81] Compiling Control.Lens.Internal.List ( src/Control/Lens/Internal/List.hs, dist/build/Control/Lens/Internal/List.o )
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.4.3.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package primitive-0.6.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package vector-0.11.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package tagged-0.8.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package template-haskell ... linking ... done.
Loading package reflection-2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parallel-3.2.0.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package stm-2.4.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package StateVar-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package binary-0.7.6.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-1.2.1.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hashable-1.2.3.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package nats-1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unordered-containers-0.2.5.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package semigroups-0.18.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-compat-0.4.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package void-0.7.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package contravariant-1.3.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package distributive-0.4.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package comonad-4.2.7.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bifunctors-5.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package exceptions-0.8.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package prelude-extras-0.4.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package profunctors-5.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package base-orphans-0.4.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package semigroupoids-5.0.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package free-4.12.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package adjunctions-4.2.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package kan-extensions-4.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
[ 4 of 81] Compiling Control.Lens.Internal.TH ( src/Control/Lens/Internal/TH.hs, dist/build/Control/Lens/Internal/TH.o )
[ 5 of 81] Compiling Control.Lens.Internal.Coerce ( src/Control/Lens/Internal/Coerce.hs, dist/build/Control/Lens/Internal/Coerce.o )
[ 6 of 81] Compiling Control.Lens.Internal.Instances ( src/Control/Lens/Internal/Instances.hs, dist/build/Control/Lens/Internal/Instances.o )
[ 7 of 81] Compiling Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom ( src/Control/Lens/Internal/Zoom.hs, dist/build/Control/Lens/Internal/Zoom.o )

src/Control/Lens/Internal/Zoom.hs:50:1:
    semigroupoids-5.0.0.4:Data.Functor.Bind can't be safely imported! The module itself isn't safe.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
equ-0.2.1 depends on lens-4.13 which failed to install.
lens-4.13 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: could you please list `ghc --version`,  `cabal --version`, `ghc-pkg list`

Comment: could you also give us the error that happens when you do a `cabal install lens`

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I have added the information requested

Comment: easiest thing probably would be to upgrade cabal/ghc to a recent version (ghc-7.10.2/cabal > 1.18) and use `cabal sandboxes` i guess

Comment: with
```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4
```I got no errors building:
Building lens-4.13...
Installed lens-4.13
Configuring equ-0.2.1...
Building equ-0.2.1...
Installed equ-0.2.1